# When opening something in my operating system and touching the lid the laptop makes a loud sound. What can I do to stop it?

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I open something and the hard drive is running, if I touch the lid it makes a weird loud sound. The laptop is just three weeks old. It's an an Acer Aspire 5742z.

Answer (score 2):

Return it for a repair under the warranty. Seriously, laptops should not be making funny noises. That's a sure sign that something significant is wrong and needs to be replaced with a manufacturer part. I suggest the following 7 steps to rectifiying the problem:

1. Backup your data.
2. Backup your data.
3. Backup your data.
4. Backup your data.
5. Backup your data.
6. Backup your data.
7. Return the laptop under warranty and have it repaired.

Comment: I would give you +6 if I could.